# python Logging file don't write

Tags: python

```
...
file_log = 'E:/key.txt'
...
def OnKeyboardEvent(event):
   logging.basicConfig(filename=file_log, level=logging.DEBUG,
                       format='%(message)')
   logging.log(10, chr(event.Ascii))
   return True
```

I can't see the error on this code. This function doesn't write on that file_log

Comment: Does the program has the needed permissions to write to E:/key.txt?

Comment: sorry but, how can i do that? How can i give permissions to write on python?

Comment: Im trying with that, but i can not get any result.  import os
os.chmod("E:/key.txt","0o777")